# Disabling AngularJS debug data in a gulp / typescript production build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, gulp

What is the best way to disable debug data from a gulp production build? The [documented](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production) way to disable debug data is:

```
myApp.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}]);
```

I'm using [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) to build the app. Since Typescript has no conditional compilation, I have no idea how I could set the parameter from true to false in a gulp production build without changing the code.

The only solution I can think of is to conditionally add `debug.ts` or `release.ts` to the `gulp.src` for `gulp-typescript`. Do you know a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [gulp-ng-constant](https://github.com/guzart/gulp-ng-constant) for application configuration. [Here is](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/issues/346#issuecomment-74419295) good practical example. The good thing is that `constant`s are available during `config` phase, it suits your case.

But adding config files conditionally is also the appropriate way.